# JSON Parsing issue with C# and RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net, restsharp

I am parsing the following JSON:

```
{
result: [
  {
    EventType: {
    EventTypeDesc: "horse-racing",
    events: {
      Local: {
        Events: {
          530857: {
            Venue: "Northam",
            StateCode: "WA",
            CountryCode: "AUS"
            },
          530858: {
            Venue: "Caulfield",
            StateCode: "VIC",
            CountryCode: "AUS"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I can access the element through following code:

> responseDeserializeObject.result[0].EventType.events.Local.Events["530857"].Venue

However, the following C# code doesn't work:

```
dynamic responseDeserializeObject = HttpGetResponse(endPoint);
foreach (var event in responseDeserializeObject.result[0].EventType.events.Local.Events)
{
  Console.WriteLine(event.Venue);
  Console.WriteLine(event.StateCode);
  Console.WriteLine(event.CountryCode);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You have a typo in the `Console.Writeline(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Events` is a dictionary, so you need to get `KeyValuePair` in the `foreach` loop and access it's `Value` property. And also change the scoped variable name `event`, it will not compile, `event` is a reserved word.

```
dynamic responseDeserializeObject = HttpGetResponse(endPoint);
foreach (var ev in responseDeserializeObject.result[0].EventType.events.Local.Events)
{
  var value = ev.Value;

  Console.WriteLine(value.Venue);
  Console.WriteLine(value.StateCode);
  Console.WriteLine(value.CountryCode);
}
```

Comment: This, plus `WriteLine` and use another variable name. Surely, `var event` doesn't compile?

Comment: Sorry mechanically get that name